# how can I navigate the pictures in css

Tags: css, html

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
background-image: url("http://intro-webdesign.com/CSS/assignment-
2/images/flywheel.jpg");
 background-size:900px 250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #cccccc;
padding:10px;
margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
} 
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
background:white;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius:10;
padding:20px 50px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
.left
 {
margin:150px 900px 0px 2px;
width:20px;
padding:20px;
 border:30px;
height:150px;
background-color:#669900;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
.right
{
margin:0px 900px 0px 2px;
width:200px;
padding:20px;
 height:150px;
background-color:#669900;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
.bottom
{
margin:0px 900px 2px 2px;
width:200px;
padding:20px;
height:150px;
background-color:#669900;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
</style>
 </head>
<body>
  <h1><font color="white">llo World!</h1>
 <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class  = "current">Team</a>
        <a href="#">History</a>
        <a href="#">USA ultimate</a>
     </nav>
        <img class="left" 
    src="https://hiphappy.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/people-playing.jpg">
            <img class="right" 
    src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/yanlev/yanlev1203/yanlev1
    20300149/12968910-group-of-young-people-playing-volleyball-on-the-beach-
    Stock-Photo.jpg">
        <img class="bottom" 
    src="https://aos.iacpublishinglabs.com/question/aq/1400px-788px/how-
     many-people-play-video-games_71f31bc8e3ca06e9.jpg?
     domain=cx.aos.ask.com"
 </body>
 </html>
```

how to navigate for multiple pages like home has some content and history has some other content like that....
The link to the current page should be styled differently from the other links.
The images should be part of the page now. How to get different pages for different navigated things.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to navigate the pages like home has different content and history  some different content like that...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do with the background-image... Crop it? I think you mean make it look beautiful:

```
body {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For the current link why don't you just add some styles to that .current class?

```
.current {
    color: green;
}
```

As for the links going to different pages, if you are doing this the classic html,css way you simply need different .html files for each page. So one of the links can be `<a href="about.html">About</a>`